# Scrolling a page with javascript when there is autofocus on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i scroll the page to the bottom when i use javascript focus on page load?

```
$(".answer-input").focus();

if( $(".alert-error") != [] ){
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}else{
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

The problem is that there is no `.alert-error` on page the page is still scrolled to the bottom. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery returns an empty array if it does not find any matching element but that is not the way to compare an empty array. Use `length` property of the arrar to check if it is 0 or not.

```
if($(".alert-error").length){ // or if($(".alert-error").length != 0)
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}else{
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should check using like this :

```
if( $(".alert-error").length > 0 )
{

}
```